# is there a way to easily implement view first pattern in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lift

is there a way to easily implement the **view first pattern** in rails? Perhaps in a way it is done in [Lift](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/View_First) Famework?

How would you do it?

For some part MVC is great but often i run into problems, where i miss the Lift way with view first.